# Tracking user id using with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am fairly new to Google Analytics and Tag Manager world. I am trying to add user id to ga events. For example I would like to add user id in case a google analytic event occurred.

What is the best practice to store userId at client side?

1. In Cookie?
2. In pages with a metatag?
3. Or something else?

Comment: Are you using Universal Analytics? It has a "User ID" feature: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id.

Answer (score 3):

you have to pass it as a dataLayer variable and add a macro to pass it to the GA, by setting additional fields in GA UA code: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/4565987

So to answer your question, you should store it in dataLayer (so basically in javascript) and pass on to GTM.

If you know how to use GTM properly it actually doesn't matter if you store this value directly in dataLayer, or in cookie, or in metatag, since you could then extract it from all mentioned locations by using js, but simplest one is the dataLayer.

Answer (score 2):

I would store it in the dataLayer.

```
dataLayer = [{
    'userId': 'abcdefg123456'
}]
```

Then if you want to reference it in an event, just pass `{{userId}}` as a custom dimension.

Comment: Can you give any more context here?

Answer (score 2):

how complicated they made all this...

NOTE: This is short how-to for GoogleTagManager + Univarsal GAnalytics + user id... I am using the dataLayer to fire custom events and to unify sessions of our registered users.

1) create and empty array dataLayer before the GTM code on every page (in Rails you can set it in application.html/haml):

```
<script>
    dataLayer = [];
</script>
```

2) then push your user id to the array:

```
<script>
    dataLayer.push({
      "&uid": "#{YOUR-BACKEND-USER-ID}"
    });
</script>
```

3) Now, add your GTM code

```
(function (w, d, s, l, i) {
    w[l] = w[l] || [];
    w[l].push({
        'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
        event: 'gtm.js'
    });
    var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j = d.createElement(s),
        dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
    j.async = true;
    j.src =
        '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
    f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
})(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-XXXXX');
```

4) Log into your tag manager account and create a new Macro "uid" of data layer variable type. Set the Layer Variable Name set to **&uid**

5) Still in your tag manager edit your tag(s) (in the sidebar). Open more settings > Fields to set and add FIELD NAME: &uid | Value: {{uid}}

6) Now in google analytics account enable USER-ID view. Go to admin > account > property >tracking info > USER-ID and enable CREATE

Comment: Sorry for that... I'll review it when I have time and post a step-by-step guide.

Comment: 5) tags in the left sidebar -> configure tag -> more settings -> fields to set...

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on how the user id you want to use is generated. If you create this in the tag Manager via JS you a cookie (to propagate the id between pages) would be the easiest way - GTM can read a first party cookie (else you could use some HTML5 localstorage thingamajig, but that you would need to implement yourself).

If you generate the client id serverside you should add it (as per Blexys answer) to a datalayer for GTM:

```
dataLayer = [{
    'userID': '12345',    
}];
```

Alternatively push it to an existing dataLayer variable:

```
dataLayer.push({'userID': '123456'});
```

In the Tag Manager you then create a macro of the datalayer type that reads from the key userID. A server generated userID that spans multiple session is of course only possible for authenticated users.

Bottom line is that the Tag Manager has no way of persistent storage, so if you create the userID yourself you need cookies (which might be deleted, so it's not reliable across sessions)

Comment: This is a correct answer, you just need to add it wrapped in a script tag in body of your html before tag manager script.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass user ID in data layer variable or in cookie. It is your decision cookie or data layer. GTM is able to read from cookie also from data layer.

If You use cookie You have to configure 1st party cookie macro in GTM. If data layer You have to configure data layer variable macro in GTM.